# OpenGL ES black as alpha (transperancy)

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I decided to move my Android project to C++, and I have a problem. In the Java code I was loading my texture without an alpha value and the black color was actually my transparent color, but now I can't do this. Black color is just black, not transparent.

I am loading the texture as this:

```
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) image_data);
```

Comment: `glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);` This is not texture object state. It will not be stored with the texture, and almost certainly should not be called there.

Comment: You are right my wrong,but removing it dosent fix my problem

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal format `GL_RGB` has only three components. It has no alpha. Therefore, if you attempt to access the alpha and do something with the non-existent alpha, OpenGL will fill it in for you. With **1.0**, which is probably not what you wanted.

If you want alpha, you need to *provide* alpha. OpenGL will not magic it into existence for you, nor will it assume that black means "transparent."

Alternatively, you didn't enable blending or alpha testing.

Comment: You were right about the GL_RGB  i changed it to GL_RGBA and also changed my glBlendFunc  to glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE);  and now i get the black color as transperant.Thank you for your help